# Uploading a document of given content type invokes wrong workflow

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, content-type

**Problem summary:** Given 2 content types and a different workflow associated with each CT, one workflow works properly for it's CT but when the other CT is uploaded the wrong workflow is invoked. I have checked all settings carefully and I am stumped.

**Background:** I have a site collection which contains a document library (SP 2010 Server service pack 1). The library has been enabled for multiple content types and I have 2 custom content types which are defined on my content type hub. Re-publishing and running the timer jobs for the hub and subscribers have been done after changes.

Content Type **TeleworkAgreement** is associated with a reusable workflow named **FlexiplaceApproval** as shown here:

[image: this workflow works OK]

Content Type **FlexiplaceArchive** is associated with a reusable workflow also named **FlexiplaceArchive** as shown here:

[image: this is NOT getting invoked]

The workflow settings for the library seem correct. There is NO workflow associated with ALL content types per the dropdown box. The following shows how the FlexiplaceArchive workflow is configured to run on items of type FlexiplaceArchive:

[image: workflow Settings]

Strangely, there is an Approval Form shown in the Forms section of the designer when examining the FlexiplaceArchive workflow. There should not be because there is no Approval Task in that workflow.

I hope you can help me figure this out. Would there be a Powershell script(s) to ensure that each workflow gets invoked for its proper content type. The UI appears correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I understand this problem now and I created a workaround which is an acceptable resolution. In short, associating a workflow with a content type does not behave as one would think. If the default content type for the document library has a workflow associated with it, then that workflow will always be invoked - even if the user selects a different content type in the Document Information Panel when supplying metadata.

I posted a more complete explanation in the Technet forum for Sharepoint:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/ce672930-0876-45b5-995e-da9dbe330f95